# SSRS Report Model - filter

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

Please help !!!

I am using SSRS Model and customer requirement is to filter the data based on the userID. Is it possible to apply the filter in the SSRS Report Model ?
I need to consume the report model in the report builder.

For namedquery :

e.g. User1

select * from CompanyInformation where userID = @param1

Thanks 
Vin

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, what you need is a classic parameter use example in SSRS:

[image: Parameter Usage]

For more clarifications, please refer to the following article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220464.aspx

Comment: I am using the Report Model Project based on the underlying Data Tables and I am creating (DataSource,Data Source View,Report Model). Here user logged in I want to apply the filter on the Report Model.

Comment: So you're trying to show only the data filtered for the credentials used to view the report?  I've done this in C# on both Winforms and WPF; if that's what you're looking for, I can point you in the right direction.

Comment: Yes any direction is a help here. If I right click on the Model->Entity and set the filter?. But i am not able achieve it yet.

Comment: I am able to apply the filters  using the GetUserID() function but this is not filtering the records showing  me true/false at the report builder. Again I have to set the filter As 'True' and then it will apply the filter.

Answer (score 0):

What about making a Parameter @UserID where the User enters their User ID and then it runs the report based on that.

```
   select * from CompanyInformation 
   where userID = @UserID
```